# Why retrieving a string with a character dot(.) does not get properly

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an inventory in Visual basic that get the product name and the unit name in the database which is Microsoft Access. Everything is fine except when I retrieve a string with a character dot(.). When i retrieve a unit with a dot, the dot is place in the first index of my string.

Here is my UnitList table

[image: Unit list]

And this is what I get when i select an item with pcs. unit. It should be "pcs.".

[image]

The dot(.) character is place in first index of my string. Same result with other unit with a character dot.

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetIngredientUnit(ByVal ProductName As String, ByVal Store As Label)
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    Query = "SELECT UnitList.UnitName FROM UnitList INNER JOIN ProductStock ON UnitList.[UnitID] = ProductStock.[UnitID] where ProductName = '" & ProductName & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, con)
    Store.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar
End Sub
```

And i call the code :`GetIngredientUnit(ListViewInvStock.SelectedItems(0).Text, INVUnit)` when the index of ListBox change

Comment: What does it look like when you select sq.m.? Can you post the code for `GetIngredientUnit`

Comment: i get a unit of ".sq.m". There is already a code and i put that code when the index of ListBox change.

Comment: Try using a oledbldataadapter and dataset just to see what the value of the retrieved data is.

Answer (score 4):

Change the Label's `RightToLeft` property to `No`. This property indicates if the language in use is a right-to-left script (e.g. Arabic).

If you want to align the text to the right hand side, set the `TextAlign` property instead.

Comment: Great to hear! If it solved your problem, please Accept the answer. Happy programming!